# ¿Cómo jalar un dato de una tabla a otra tabla usando el framework web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

Si tengo la tabla:

```
db.define_table('personal',
    Field('persona', 'string'),
    format='%(persona)s'
)
```

Y esta tabla:

```
db.define_table('personal_registro',
    Field('dni','string'),
    Field('direccion','string'),
    Field('persona', 'string'), 
    format='%(persona)s'
)
```

Se que puedo enlazar el campo `persona` con un `Field('persona', 'reference personal'),` pero, ¿hay otra u otras formas de hacerlo?, y ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo entendido que la forma:

```
Field('persona', 'reference personal')
```

Es relativamente nueva, por lo menos para mi que no lo uso hace algún tiempo. Recuerdo que para lograr el mismo efecto yo lo hacía de esta otra forma:

```
db.define_table('personal',
    Field('persona', 'string'), 
    format='%(persona)s'
)

db.define_table('personal_registro',
    Field('dni', 'string'),
    Field('direccion','string'),
    Field('persona', db.personal), 
    format='%(persona)s'
)
```

Habría que probar si esta forma sigue funcionando ya que en la documentación actual solo veo que hacen uso de `reference`.